# vue.prototype is undefined on sweealert in vue cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, sweetalert2, vuejs3

The following code:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";

import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import sweetalert from 'vue-sweetalert2'
window.URL='//127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .use(sweetalert)
  .use(VueAxios, axios)
  .mount("#app");
```

Gives me this error in vue cli:

> Uncaught TypeError: vue.prototype is undefined

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`vue-sweetalert2` is not yet supporting Vue@3, as you can see [here](https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2/blob/master/package.json#L54) `vue-sweetalert2` using Vue@2 that reason why you're seeing that error `(vue.prototype is undefined)` B'cause `prototype` is not available in Vue@3.

I have created a support issue [here](https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2/issues/115), you can keep track on this.